# How to display image in django using HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I am trying to display the image of python script output using below lines but instead of displaying in browser, code downloading the file instead of displaying

this is the function i have created in views.py:

def adc(request):
file = "C:\Users\TheBoss\Downloads\New_test.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Graph')

```
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Video Device - Not Responding'], label = 'Video Device - Not Responding')
#plt.plot(df['Date'], df['30th Apr'], 'b', label = '30-Apr')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=6)
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('Condition Count')

# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('Condition')

# function to show the plot
plt.legend()
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\TheBoss\\Downloads\\test.png')


image_data = open("C:\\Users\\TheBoss\\Downloads\\test.png", "rb").read()
return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="test/png")
```

Comment: Try settings `Content-Disposition` header to `inline`. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment) is an example how to do that. I think Django sets this automatically to `attachment` for file response. Additional info about `Content-Disposition` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

Comment: thanks for the response.....i tried but still its downloading instead of displaying ....

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this should be enough to display image inline.

```
def adc(request): 
    file = "C:\Users\TheBoss\Downloads\New_test.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Graph')

    plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Video Device - Not Responding'], label = 'Video Device - Not Responding')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=6)
    plt.ylabel('Condition Count')
    plt.title('Condition')
    plt.legend()
    
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')
    return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type="test/png")
```

It should display as an image in most browsers and if you want to insert the image in HTML, you'd use a simple

```
<img src="{% url 'my_image' %}">
```

I know from experience that this works in Edge, Firefox and Opera. Sometimes browsers need additional convincing to display image inline and in those cases setting the header `Content-Disposition` to `inline` usually works.

Comment: Thanks i tried but its also downloading file not displaying